# Conflict between shaders and QPainter in paintGL() for rendering 2D text

Tags: qt, opengl, text, qpainter

I have the following class inheriting from `QOpenGLWidget` and `QOpenGLFunctions`:

```
class OpenGLWidget : public QOpenGLWidget, protected QOpenGLFunctions
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    OpenGLWidget();
    virtual ~OpenGLWidget();

    void initializeGL();
    void paintGL()
    {
       QPainter painter(this);

       painter.beginNativePainting();
       glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
       // Calls OpenGL draw functions with VBOs
       m_viewport.render(m_shader, m_entities);
       painter.endNativePainting();

       painter.drawText(0, 0, width(), height(), Qt::AlignCenter, "Hello World!");

    }
    void resizeGL(int width, int height);

    [...]
}
```

"Hello World" is drawn as intended, but the 3D scene is broken. I should have 3D axis in the center and in the top-right of the screen:

[image]

To me, it seems that the vertex and fragment shaders I'm using are the source of the problem. Otherwise, given the simplicity of the code and the examples I've found, it should work.

A good output would be:

[image]

with the "Hello World" at the center. This is what I get when I comment the `QPainter` calls.

Comment: What happens if you create the QPainter after your custom GL draw code?

Comment: Same problem. I still have to wrap the custom GL draw code with the enclosing painter functions `beginNativePainting` and `beginNativePainting`. But even without them it doesn't draw anything.

Comment: I would then suggest to run the app in apitrace and check if there's some messed up GL state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that your shader program is released when you use QPainter. Bind the shader program before OpenGL calls and release it afterwards. It should fix it.

```
painter.beginNativePainting();
// Bind shader program
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
// Calls OpenGL draw functions with VBOs
m_viewport.render(m_shader, m_entities);
// Release shader program
painter.endNativePainting();
```